# "Your browser does not support html" - Http get request

Tags: javascript, html, http, get, construct-2

I am trying to get some data from a webserver, at http://orbyte-games.pe.hu/hosting/theAmateur/training_01, and when I use python to get the content, it returns the correct data.

However, when I try to access it from Javascript (Construct 2 namely) it gives an html webpage, ironically with the content "Your browser does not support html"! This is quite frustrating, because firstly I don't need to use html, and secondly because of the irony of the sentence, which might just be me not understanding the dynamics of it.

Comment: It might be valuable to provide some information regarding what, specifically, you're doing.

Comment: Can we see the JavaScript code you've written relating to this?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2

Comment: @CyberneticTwekGuruOrc Well, it's not Javascript, I use Construct 2, which is a graphical IDE for javascript, so the code is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am loading saves from a webserver, so that the community can create levels. It could be my host provider, since this HTML page is quite obscure.